# Reading keys from a virtualized Windows Registry

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

My older application writes to registry (which ends up being virtualized), now I want the installer to actually read this data, when I tried directly from LOCAL_MACHINE (I didn't know the key was virtualized) I got error, then when I decided to try reading directly from the virtualized key, I got error as well.

Windows 2008 server 64 bits, and my application is 32bits, UAC is enabled.

So is it actually possible to read from a virtualized windows registry directly?

Now I need to read this data, BUT.

This doesn't work.

```
  if regkeyexists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\App') then
  begin
    msgBox('Exists', mbinformation, mb_ok);
  end else begin
    msgBox('Doesnt exists', mbinformation, mb_ok);
  end;
```

And this doesn't work as well.

```
  if regkeyexists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\App') then
  begin
    msgBox('Exists', mbinformation, mb_ok);
  end else begin
    msgBox('Doesnt exists', mbinformation, mb_ok);
  end;
```

It says the Key doesn't exist

So now I can't actually read the data?
I've checked and the path is OK.

Comment: Either use `RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32...`, or `RegKeyExists(HKLM32...` and remove that `Wow6432Node` from your key path. Using such root key reads from `Wow6432Node` node on 64-bit systems.

Comment: I've tried and doesn't seem to be working still..

What's the difference between HKLM_32 and HKLM? does it points directly to the Wow6432Node?

Since my application is 32bits, when it writes to the registry, it actually writes to this node (when i run in a 64bit system, which is what i'm doing right now), this is why i try to read from there.

Comment: The problem actually is because Inno Setup runs with admin privileges, even though my windows user is an administrator, if execute my application using "run as administrator", it writes to the LOCAL_MACHINE correctly...and if i dont, it can't read from the virtualized key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could resolve my problem using some workaround, so just to let others know in case someone else needs it.

What happened was that even being an administrator user, in Windows 2008 server with UAC enabled, my application (which was not run as administrator) used to record its registry in the virtualized key, while the installation in Inno Setup could write to the true LOCAL_MACHINE, making the application's registry invisible to my application and vice-versa.

As i'm releasing a new version in which i have to make sure the app registries will be in LOCAL_MACHINE, i ran a separated application using 'ShellExecAsOriginalUser' to actually export the virtualized keys to a file, and then import back to LOCAL_MACHINE through Inno Setup.

I'm thankful to all the answeres here!

Comment: That's essentially the same method I used when I had to do the same. A non manifested application with `runasoriginaluser` that read from the "original" path (which is in turn virtualised by Windows) and moved to the corretc location setup by the admin installer.

Comment: Interesting..These Windows virtualization on registry mappings can become sometimes a headache!

Comment: I have to agree...
Fortunately it wasn't me who wrote the old code.
But it was me who had to fix it.. haha.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualised keys are per-user data; this means that even if you were able to successfully read one from the installer, you would only be reading the settings of one user, not all users (and as you've found, there's a good chance you won't even be able to read that one).

Normally you can just ignore virtualisation until the time comes to upgrade your application and mark it with a compatibility manifest, at which point it loses virtualisation and you have to handle the registry correctly.  So I'm assuming that this is the case you're finding yourself in.

In this case, the correct resolution is not in the installer, it's in your application.  Your installer should either not write to the registry at all or should store read-only defaults in HKLM.  On startup, your application should first try to read settings from locations in this order (only moving down the list if it cannot find the value there):

1. HKCU\Software\YourCompany\YourApp\SettingName
2. the VirtualStore location of the HKLM key you were mistakenly using previously
3. the HKLM key possibly written by the installer
4. some internal default value

When your application saves settings, it must write only #1, never anywhere else.  Also note that you must follow this list for each individual setting -- it's possible that some settings are in HKCU, some are virtualised, and some are only in HKLM.